# Whats the best way to convert a bitmap into a circular bitmap

Tags: java, c#, android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm trying to convert a "rectangular" bitmap into a circular one with a border. I wrote this code:

```
using Android.Graphics;
namespace MyNamespace
{
 public static class BitmapExtension
 {
    public static Bitmap GetCircularBitmap(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        paint.AntiAlias = true;
        canvas.DrawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.Color = Color.Black;
        canvas.DrawCircle(bitmap.Width / 2, bitmap.Height / 2, bitmap.Width / 2, paint);
        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        // Border
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.StrokeWidth = 2;
        paint.AntiAlias = true;

        canvas.DrawCircle(
                canvas.Width / 2,
                canvas.Width / 2,
                canvas.Width / 2 - 2 / 2,
                paint);

        // Release pixels on original bitmap.
        bitmap.Recycle();

        return result;
    }               
 }
}
```

This works great so far, however, since this code is used in a RecyclerView sometimes it just doesn't draw right:

[image: Image draw out of place.]

As you can see, the image is drawn slightly out of place. So i got two questions:

1. What causes this strange behavior to happen?
2. Is there a way to improve my *GetCircularBitmap* Method? Since performance is important, it must be very fast.

**Update: Solution**

I used [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) together with a [Circle Transformation](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Transformations-Guide) to display my Images. It also improved the performance a lot and enabled a good practice for Image Caching.

Comment: Isn't the second result just caused by the second image not being square? You'll simply have to start by cutting out the center square of it and using just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

First add this to yout gradle file:

`dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}`

In your XML layout:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="24"
android:layout_height="24"
android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

And in your Java code use it as you would like any other ImageView.

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try, for I'm a little doubtful on third party librarys when it comes to performance issues.

Comment: I have used in a RecyclerView and have not faced any issues. But maybe you can take a look at the code in the GitHub repo?

Comment: I tried it out. Might be a good solution for other apps, but since I'm loading my images in an asynchronous way into the CircleImageView and use SetImageBitmap when i come back somehow it doesn't work out. 
The image just isn't displayed after the code returns from the async request (however it worked with my own code i posted in the starter post).

Comment: where are you loading the image from?

Comment: If you are loading the image from the web i would say using Picasso is the best way. You don't have to worry about AsyncTasks or Loaders.         http://square.github.io/picasso/